# Rails model many-to-many name convention with underscore

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-models

i have 3 tables (products, orders, products_orders)
i have 3 models files (product.rb, order.rb, product_order.rb)

therefore 3 classes

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible ...
    has_many :product_orders
    has_many :orders, :through => :product_orders
end

class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible ...
    has_many :product_orders
    has_many :products, :through => :product_orders
end

class ProductOrder < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :order_id, :product_id, ...
    belongs_to :product
    belongs_to :order
end
```

firts question.. can i have primary key (id) in products_orders table without problem ? I read here http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html about some possible problems but im not sure about it.

second question.. if i try to generate ER diagram (rake erd) it tell me this:

Warning: Ignoring invalid model ProductOrder (table product_orders does not exist)

**# the missing 's' is the problem which i dont know how to fix (i just want to have that underscore model because its confusing to have model name different from table name i think)**

Warning: Ignoring invalid association :product_orders on Order (model ProductOrder exists, but is not included in domain)

Warning: Ignoring invalid association :product_orders on Product (model ProductOrder exists, but is not included in domain)

Please help, its my first testing rails app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello thank for your help,

```
class ProductsOrder < ActiveRecord::Base
  set_table_name "products_orders"
```

is a solution

Comment: I realize this post is old, but the `set_table_name` method is deprecated as of Rails 3.2. `self.table_name` is now prefered.

Answer (score 2):

What's the name of the table for your `ProductOrders` model, and if it's not `product_orders` how is Rails meant to know where to look?

Either fix your table name or model name so that it fits convention, or explicitly specify the table name with `self.table_name = ...`.

Also, typically people don't define a model for these kind of associations, they use [`has_and_belongs_to_many`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_and_belongs_to_many-association). This is unless extra information needs to be stored along with the association.